# Rest call at componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I am call a REST service in my React component's componentDidMount:

```
loadData: function () {
    return $.getJSON(this.props.server+"/xxxxx/"+this.props.params.promotionid);

},
componentDidMount: function () {
    this.loadData().success(function (data) {
        console.log("After success");
        console.log(data);
        if(this.isMounted())
        {
            this.setState({
                prom: data
                //release: data.Release
            });
        }
    }.bind(this))
}
```

This works even without documentation suggestion to include an if(this.isMounted()), there. Plesee note the commented line. We will need to comment this out in order to work. The thing is that if the data I get from the server has a subobject in it, it does not work even with the isMounted(). eg:

```
{
PromotionId: 1,
Description: "Hello three",
Category: "serviceid",
SpecialID: 23666,
ProjectManager: "Tarkidi Touvouda",
Requestor: "George Klapas",
Readiness: false,
SignOff: false,
SourceDestination: "developement-uat",
Status: "pending",
ReleaseId: 2,
Release: {
    ReleaseId: 2,
    ReleaseName: "Fall Second",
    ReleaseDate: "2015-10-05T00:00:00",
    ReleaseDeadline: "2015-10-05T00:00:00",
    ModifiedDate: "2015-10-21T12:48:45.753"
},
PromotionAssets: null,
ModifiedDate: "2015-10-21T12:48:45.753"
```

}

I get the data at render() as follows

```
var p=this.state.prom;
var rel=p.Release;
```

I get an error when I try to access rel.ReleaseName that cannot find Releasename of undefined. The only way to make it work is removing the comment you saw (that is to say, having a separate field in state that will hold Release object) and then :

```
var rel=this.state.release;
```

Subsequent calls to Release object are successful. Why should I do that? I mean have a separate state field for this?

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` is an async call, which means that the execution continues while waiting for the response. So your script calls `componentDidMount` and after that continues with `render()` without waiting for the results.

Because of this in the first round of `render()`, the variable `this.state.prom` is `undefined`. Due to this a call to `this.state.prom.Release` throws an error, because you cannot get a property of an undefined object.

A simple solution might be to wait until the AJAX call has been finished an the state has been updated:

```
render: function() {
  if(!this.state.prom) {
    return <div>loading ...</div>;
  }
  // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I know it is async. It calls the function into the success. This is not the problem.

Comment: I'm not saying that the async call does not work. But the first time `render()` is called, `this.state.prom` is undefined, because the call has not been completed yet. You might want to check this out by calling the debugger on your render function or simply paste `console.log(this.state)` inside render to see what your state is at the point of rendering. I am quite sure, that `this.state` does not have a property `prom` when the component is first rendered, neither does it have a property `release`. Check it out!

Comment: Another fix would be to give the shape of the state in the `getInitialState` function, such as `getInitialState: function() { return { prom: {} }; }`. If you do this, `this.state.prom` is always defined, which is why `this.state.prom.Release` does not throw an error (even though the value is `undefined` in the initial render process). Be aware that the solution I have initially posted does not work when using this method.

Comment: I have done this already just for this reason; to be defined. The problem is the nested object inside prom, Releases.